# Linear Regression in python with multiple outputs

Tags: python, linear-regression

I have a time series dataset which represented as following:

```
x=[ 
       [12.19047619,  18.28571429,   6.0952381 ] ,

       [ 80.98765432,  14.17283951,  11.13580247 ] ,

       [ 50.82644628,  16.26446281,   9.14876033 ] , .... ]


and to predicted -->
 Y  = [13.9,  18,   14.987]
```

How I can use LASSO and SVR linear regression models in python to predict Y (which represented as a vector as shown in the above example)

Comment: What is time series in this? It seems data with 3 features only.

Comment: These features are changing over time, so vector # 1 in x is taken at time t(i) and vector # 2 is taken at time t(i+1) and so on

Comment: Why are you calling it `multiple outputs`? There is only one output per row or sample or observation of X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Lasso and SVM are available in sklearn library. Lasso: [sklearn.linear_model.Lasso](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html). SVM: [sklearn.svm.SVT](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html)

An example from Lasso page:

```
>>> from sklearn import linear_model
>>> clf = linear_model.Lasso(alpha=0.1)
>>> clf.fit([[0,0], [1, 1], [2, 2]], [0, 1, 2])
Lasso(alpha=0.1, copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, max_iter=1000, normalize=False, positive=False, precompute=False, random_state=None, selection='cyclic', tol=0.0001, warm_start=False)
>>> print(clf.coef_)
[0.85 0. ]
>>> print(clf.intercept_)
0.15...
```

In your case clf.fit looks like this:

```
clf.fit(X, Y)
```

X should be the size (nn,n)
Y should be the size nn
Where nn is the number of observations (points) and n is the number of variables. So rows in X are observations and columns are different variables.

If you have more variables than observations then you should read [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/223486/modelling-with-more-variables-than-data-points) about the problems you can have with it and how to solve them.

Comment: Thanks @keiv.fly ... I followed the exact same steps but it gives --> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [4, 3] .... This is when I have 4 sample and each sample with 3 dimensions  and the output is expected to be a vector with 3 dimensions

Comment: What is the output of x.shape and y.shape?

Comment: x.shape --> (4,3) .... y.shape --> (3,) .... I am not sure but it seems I should take the transpose of x before fitting?

Comment: please check the edited response

Comment: y should be 4. You have 3 x variables. For every observation (row) you should have all x variables and one y. So in your case you have 4 observations (rows of x) and you should have 4 observations for y.

Comment: Please accept the answer if you find it helpful.